# How to create and call sybase stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sybase, sap-ase, splunk

i have sybase databse with following stored procedure ,

i am also running this query from splunk db connect app

I have tried CALL stored_procedure and
EXEC stored_procedure

```
create procedure sp__cpu_busy_thread_test
as
begin
select @@servername,@@version
end
return(0)
```

Comment: Did you read the [manual](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1600/doc/html/san1390612426772.html) ?

Comment: i had doubt, that SP has return(0), so does it return empty result every time i call the SP

Comment: There will be a 1-row, 2-column result set for every call. The question is if you are correctly capturing it , given how you call it.

Comment: How do you call the proc, which result do you expect and in which format?
For instance if you want to save the result in a variable, you have to initialize them as [return parameters](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc32300.1570/html/sqlug/sqlug686.htm).

Comment: Iam calling it as CALL sp__cpu_busy_thread_test
, and getting this error- JZ0R2: No result set for this qury

Comment: how to capture result of SP in sybase

Comment: `call` is not a valid ASE-command, use `exec sp__cpu_busy_thread_test` instead

Comment: i tried exec as well , but getting No result set for this query. error

Comment: Did you check the splunk docs as as it implies direct stored proc calls are not supported - the link is a few years old but lists a workaround:
https://answers.splunk.com/answers/117085/need-to-get-data-from-a-stored-procedure-in-db-using-the-data-connect-app.html#answer-386947

Answer (score 1):

To create you can do it like this:

```
  create procedure sp__cpu_busy_thread_test
  as
  select @@servername,@@version
  go
```

And to execute it would be simply:

```
  execute sp__cpu_busy_thread_test
  go
```

or

```
  exec sp__cpu_busy_thread_test
  go
```

or if it's the first statement

```
  sp__cpu_busy_thread_test
  go
```

Comment: I am getting errors like, Execute cursor 'jconnect_implicit_1' is declared on a procedure which has more than one SQL statement for the declaration of this cursor to be legal the procedure should have a single SELECT statement cluase

Comment: and another error is declared on a procedure which contains a non SELECT or a SELECT with a COMPUTE cluase. For the declaration of this cursor to be legal it should have a single SELECT statement witout a COMPUTE clause.

Comment: see my previous comment where the docs for splunk imply you cannot call a stored procedure directly with db connect hence the error about it not being a single select statement.

Comment: so is there any way that we can call stored procedure in splunk db connect app